# "Сообщили, что" или "сообщили о том, что"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой вариант предпочтительнее: "Сообщили, что защита прошла успешно" или "Сообщили о том, что защита прошла успешно"?

Answer (score 2):

Коррелят О ТОМ в придаточных изъяснительных является **факультативным**, тем не менее выбор решения должен быть как-то обоснован.

1) Можно обратить внимание на то, что коррелят часто употребляется в текстах на политические темы, например: "Президент сообщил о том, что достигнута главная цель ―  политическое единение всей нашей страны, наших народов", Понятно, что это обобщение его речи, выделение главной мысли, поэтому "о том" здесь вполне уместно. О том - это название темы и ее краткое изложение.

2) **Сообщили, что защита прошла успешно**. В этом случае это полная и исчерпывающая информация, поэтому коррелят здесь был бы лишним.

Comment: А почему в 2 "о том" не может быть "обобщением речи, выделением главной мысли"? Очень размытые обоснования.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в 2  нечего обобщать, это информация, которая полностью укладывается в одно предложение. Но это мое мнение.  А как Вы стали бы выбирать нужный вариант? Кстати, полной факультативности для О ТОМ в любом случае не получится, в некоторых случаях  он невозможен, например:  приказал, чтобы. А в других случаях он может быть лишним, тогда зачем он?  Только вот интересно, когда он лишний, как Вы думаете?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, наблюдается тенденция употреблять "о том, что" вместо "что" – повсеместно и без всякой надобности. Однако есть семантическая разница. Не думаю, что существуют строгие правила на этот счет, поэтому поделюсь моим субъективным пониманием. Одно дело, когда вам сообщили факт, другое - о факте. Во втором случае хочется спросить: "А что именно сообщили об этом факте?"

"Сообщили, что защита прошла успешно" имеет конкретный  и ограниченный смысл, близкий к косвенной речи — пересказу сообщения.

"Сообщили о том, что защита прошла успешно" оставляет простор для понимания. Возможно, это был некий рассказ о том, как прошла защита, со счастливым концом. 
Возможно, защита - особое событие, тогда добавление "о том" придает фразе  оттенок некоторой повышенной значимости (в этом смысле "сообщить, что" отличается от "сообшить о том, что" примерно в той же мере, как "сообщить" отличается от "сделать сообщение").

Answer (score 1):

**Частотность выражений** в Нацкорпусе: ***сообщили, что***  ― 1517 примеров, ***сообщили о том, что*** ― 47 примеров.

Из этого следует, что указательное слово ***о том*** популярностью не пользуется и его желательно использовать в определенных случаях. Попробуем **представить ситуации,** когда применяются эти выражения.

(1) **Конкретный диалог**: ― Звонили по поводу защиты. ― Что сказали? ― Сообщили, что защита прошла успешно.

(2) **Одна из новостей**: Сегодня СМИ сообщили о том, что защита диссертации на тему... прошла успешно.

О чем сегодня сообщают СМИ? Вот перечень новостей: о том, о том, и о том.

Что СМИ сообщают (по этой теме)? Сообщают, что...

Названая тенденция просматривается в примерах из Нацкорпуса:  **новостная тема (о том) и конкретное содержание определенной темы (что).**

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта равноправны. Однако, обратите внимание, что в немалом количестве случаев часть "о том" может быть опущена без ущерба качеству текста.

Comment: Предпочтительно опускать то, что можно опустить. К сожалению, наблюдается тенденция употреблять "о том, что" повсеместно и без всякой надобности

Comment: @М_Г в данном случае никакой стилистической/грамматической ошибки нет. А тенденция есть, вы правы — но что поделать.

Comment: @М_Г обоснуйте ваше утверждение, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какое утверждение из двух?

Comment: @М_Г первое, очевидно.

Comment: Многословие, или «лишние слова», ослабляют действенность литературного произведения, делают его менее доступным для читателя, поэтому в задачу редактора входит выявление и устранение так называемых «лишних слов». Слово, употребление которого не находит оправдания и без которого текст ничего не теряет ни в смысле, ни в оттенке смысла, ни в эмоциональной окрашенности, называют «лишним». (Розенталь. http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/72.htm)

Comment: @М_Г послушайте, так "то, что можно опустить" отнюдь не лишние слова! Не путайте факультативность и излишность. Да и Розенталь писал о *литературных произведениях* в прошлом веке. Так что, увы, "Литературное редактирование" не обосновывает ваши слова.